# String.format() is Capitalizing Arguments

Tags: java, string-formatting

I have a String format String:

```
String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ("
    + "%S INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER NOT NULL, %s TEXT NOT NULL)",
    SPORT_TABLE, SPORT_ID, SPORT_WSID, SPORT_TITLE);
```

But my second argument (`SPORT_ID`) is being capitalized. Why is this happening? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It **is** a perfectly documented behavior even if not a well known one (probably because it's neither an obvious need nor something very useful).

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) :

> The following table summarizes the supported conversions. Conversions
>   denoted by an upper-case character (i.e. 'B', 'H', 'S', 'C', 'X', 'E',
>   'G', 'A', and 'T') are the same as those for the corresponding
>   lower-case conversion characters except that the result is converted
>   to upper case according to the rules of the prevailing Locale. The
>   result is equivalent to the following invocation of
>   String.toUpperCase()

Answer (score 10):

In your format string, you have a `%S`, and it should be a `%s`. I haven't currently found any documentation on this behavior, but all string selectors (`%s`,`%f`, etc.) should be lowercase.